# Web Based CRUD for inventory management, with ACL

Tags: php, mysql, acl, crud

So I've been teaching myself PHP to create a simple inventory management system for a small business customer of mine, whom I do other IT related work.  I've got everything working like they want, including a login, however it has no ACL or Role-Based Authentication, which is what they are now asking for.

I'm not a PHP pro, and I'm sure it shows in my code, but this company is a breeder and national distributor of certain species of live fish.  Their inventory is distributed between 4 different facilities currently, and that number could be growing to about 8 facilities in the next few months.  With the current solution, if you have a login, you see everyone's inventory.  They are wanting some sort of ACL that will have two different user levels, admin and user.  Admin level can see everyone's inventory, where user level can only see their inventory.

I've played around with the idea of trying to set up some sort of ACL, by adding a new field to the user table (MySQL) with a value of 1 or 2, and do some sort of if/then statement to determine which HTML table/SQL query to load on index.php (which is the main inventory screen, showing all products currently).  I also have static pages for each of the current users to only show their inventory, with a header listing the menu for those pages.  I need to figure out some alternate solution for that also, but that's not nearly as important as the ACL.

My question is, should I try to figure out how to add a simple ACL to my existing app (any good tutorials, because I can't find any), or should I switch to some sort of PHP framework like Yii or GroceryCRUD, and rebuild the app?  I've looked at Yii a little, but am completely lost with the information I'm seeing on it.  I know MySQL, HTML, and CSS but my PHP skills are still developing.  I'd be willing to share all my source code for my current project, if anyone was interested in seeing what I currently have.  Doubtful, but throwing that out there.

Any help is great appreciated.  Thanks!

*Scripts referenced in comments below*
login.inc.php (ignore the MD5 hashing of passwords, will be salted at a later date):

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once('config.inc.php');
require_once('functions.inc.php');

// Escape any unsafe characters before querying database
$username = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" . $username . "' AND password = '" . MD5($password) . "'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
$user_data = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

// If one row is returned, username and password are valid
if (is_object($result) && $result->num_rows == 1) {
  $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
  $_SESSION['userlevel'] = $user_data['userlevel'];
  redirect('../index.php');
} else {
  redirect('../failed.php');
}
?>
```

Comment: In your case this should be extremely easy. To speak very bluntly, you currently use `$query = "SELECT * FROM inventory";`. Whereas you should be using `if(userLevel == 'admin') { $query = "SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE user = $user"; }`

Comment: @Mave I didn't think it would be too difficult, and using a variable in my query was what I was thinking to do.  However, I guess what makes me unsure is how exactly to get the value for `userLevel` in the first place.  I assume just another SQL query?  I have 3 tables in my db, `users`, `products`, `inventory`.  `inventory` and `products` tie together using the `sku` field.

Comment: If they press submit on the log in form, you check if the info matches, right? You would. You probably use something like `SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = $user AND password = $pass`. Now, that is already set, so all you have to do is bind the `is_admin` or `user_level` column value to a variable, and put that in a $_SESSION variable. That way, you can simply call `if($_SESSION['is_admin'] == 1) { //do admin stuff }`.

Comment: @Mave The login page is a simple html form, that calls `login.inc.php`.  `login.inc.php` escapes the `$_POST` data for username/password, passes it to a query, then runs this:
`if (is_object($result) && $result->num_rows == 1) {
  $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
  redirect('../index.php');
} else {
  redirect('../failed.php');
}`

If my users table has a field called `userlevel` which is set to either 0 or 1 (0 means admin, see everything & 1 means user, see only their data) how would I update this if/else statement to set `$_SESSION['userlevel']` to the appropriate 1 or 0?

Comment: Updated OP with my current `login.inc.php`.  Not sure if this is going to work, but I'm thinking it will.  I will update my `index.php` page later this evening with an if/else statement as suggested by @Mave above.

Comment: Yep, I guess you're good. Have a go at it! :)